# Experiencing annoying sprite jitter in a Pygame platformer (unsolved but closed)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a platformer in Pygame. I, being an idiot, am not using classes, which would probably make my job easier. This is for a school project, and it's due in 2 Days, so I have no time to implement classes. I'm trying to make the player collide with the ground, but when it does, I get sprite jitter (as in, the sprite "bounces" slightly)

Here are the functions (touchingGround handles ground collision):

```
def touching(entityDat,entityRect,rlist,cpos):
    entityRect.center = (entityDat[0] - cpos[0],entityDat[1] - cpos[1])
    entityDat[4] = False
    for i in rlist:
        if entityRect.colliderect(i):
            entityDat[4] = True
            return True
def touchingGround(entityDat,entityRect,rlist,cpos,gravity):
    while touching(entityDat,entityRect,rlist,cpos):
        if entityDat[5]:
            entityDat[1] += gravity/10
        else:
            entityDat[1] -= gravity/10
        entityDat[3] = 0
    if touching(entityDat,entityRect,rlist,cpos):
        if entityDat[5]:
            entityDat[1] += entityDat[3]
        else:
            entityDat[1] -= entityDat[3]
        entityDat[3] = 0
def walk(entityDat,entityRect,rlist,cpos):
    entityDat[0] += entityDat[2]
    if touching(entityDat,entityRect,rlist,cpos):
        entityDat[0] -= entityDat[2]
        entityDat[2] = 0
```

here's the movement handler:

```
if not moveLock:
        #player movement
        touching(playerDat,playerRect,rlist,cpos)
        if jump or playerDat[3] < 4:
            playerDat[3] += gravity
        elif not touching(playerDat,playerRect,rlist,cpos):
            playerDat[3] += gravity * 2
        touchingGround(playerDat,playerRect,rlist,cpos,gravity)
        playerDat[1] += playerDat[3]
        playerDat[2] *= 0.7
        if moveRight:
            playerDat[2] += 3
        if moveLeft:
            playerDat[2] -= 3
        if playerDat[2] > -0.5 or playerDat[2] < 0.5:
            walk(playerDat,playerRect,rlist,cpos)
        if touching(playerDat,playerRect,rlist,cpos) and jump == True:
            playerDat[3] = 20
            jump = False
        playerRect.center = (playerDat[0] - cpos[0],playerDat[1] - cpos[1])
```

and here's a key for what all the values of playerDat mean:

```
playerDat = [0:xPos,1:yPos,2:xMomentum,3:yMomentum,4:touchingGround,5:goingUp?,6:direction,7:frame]
```

I'm sorry if I should have included more, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "sprite jitter".

Comment: Could you point us to the repo with the runnable code?  What platform?

Comment: "Sprite jitter" as in the sprite bounces (or jitters, which is a better word for it) slightly on the platform. The movement handler itself is in the run loop, and this is the only relevant material. The rest is handling events and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not all relevant code, so one can only take a bit of a guess, but from what I can see:

- Why do you have a `while touching(...):` in `touchingGround` ? It's not all of your code but it really looks like it should be `if touching(...):`. Is it because that's how you are implementing gravity, to make the sprite "fall"? If that's the case, you should not be doing it that way, the `while` loop will pretty much block any other update. You should update the y position each frame, during your main `while` loop (the one with the events).
- Usually if a sprite "jitters" it means that's it's going back and forth, which in turn means that its position is being changed, drawn, changed again, drawn again. That's why you should have included the loop where you actually draw the sprite. What is most likely happening is that you're checking and changing the sprite's position multiple times in the loop, and that makes it jitter.

Comment: Sorry about the irrelevant code. Thanks for the help. I have a lot of reason to believe that's not the reason, but with the info I gave you, there's no way to know that. I believe that my code can be fixed, but I think this particular thread is a lost cause. I'm going to do some more research for future reference and start again. Thanks again for the help, but my code is clean enough that I know that isn't the problem. I know from tests it has something to do with momentum and overcorrection, but I didn't supply those tests, so there was no way for anyone to know that. Sorry and thanks.